# Как через python на Android позвонить (как это делает google ассистент)

Tags: python, android

Мне надо позвонить на номер из скрипта python который будет запущен на Android.(Проект мини голосового ассистента как google ассистент )

```
import json
import pyttsx3
import speech_recognition as sr


lvlofrun = 1
while lvlofrun == 1:
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone(device_index = 1) as source:
        print('Настраиваюсь.')
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=0.5) 
        print('Слушаю...')
        audio = r.listen(source)
    print('Услышала.')
    try:
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language = 'ru-RU')
        text = query.lower()
        print(f'Вы сказали: {query.lower()}')
        if text == "протокол 0":
            print("Выполняется 0 протокол...")

        elif text == "стоп":
            lvlofrun += 1    
    except Exception as e:
            print('Ошибка:\n', traceback.format_exc())


def talk(text):
    tts.say(text)
    tts.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если через интерфейсы java, то pyjnius

```
from jnius import cast
from jnius import autoclass

Intent = autoclass('android.content.Intent')
Uri = autoclass('android.net.Uri')

intent = Intent()
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL)
intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber))

PythonService = autoclass("org.renpy.android.PythonService") #тут надо поставить то приложение которое запускает питон скипты

activity = cast("android.app.Service", PythonService.mService)
activity.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Спасибо завтра проверю

Comment: ок, расскажешь, я не проверял ;)

Comment: Проверить не вышло (т.к. не могу установить jnius на Android), но на первый взгляд ответ верный и рабочий